# Random msg in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, command, match

In a chatbot, there's a function for the bot to answer to determined command with a phrase, for example, in

```
match /^Loggy, te amo/, :use_prefix => false

  def execute(user)
    if user.name.eql? 'Cquintero6'
      @client.send_msg '/me besa a Carlos'
      @client.send_msg 'Io también te jamón <3'
    else
      @client.send_msg "#{user.name}, ¿En serio crees que amaria a una basurilla como tú? Sáquese. "
    end
  end
```

When I write "Loggy, te amo", the bot answers in the chat, depending on the user. The question is, how can I make a list of answers so the bot select one random answer? Thanks! (Random strings of " @Client.send_msg" )

Comment: are you asking how to write an array of strings and select and random one? or are you asking where there is a list of "random phrases" you can use?

Comment: How to write an array of strings and so the bot select one! Yep

Comment: added an example of ERB to my answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructing an array is simple:

```
phrases = [
  "a phrase",
  "another phrase"
]
```

You can also use the [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) gem. See its README for options, but here's an example:

```
phrases = 10.times.map { Faker::Company.catch_phrase }
```

At this point you just need to select a random entry, which is simple:

```
random_phrase = phrases.sample
@client.send_msg random_phrase
```

Say you also wanted to get a random phrase but change the text according to a runtime variable. Here's one way to do it:

```
require 'erb'
phrases = [
  "your name is <%= name %>"
]
name = user.name
random_phrase = ERB.new(phrases.sample).result(binding)
@client.send_msg random_phrase
```

This compiles the [ERB](http://apidock.com/ruby/ERB) string at runtime

Comment: Extremely minor nitpick, but if you want an array of 10 Faker catch phrases, why use `10.times.map { etc }` rather than `Array.new(10) { etc }`? Also, depending on the complexity of what you are doing, using `String#%` is somewhat simpler than Erb: `phrases = ["Your name is %{name}",...]; random_phrase = phrases.sample % { name: user.name}`

Comment: thanks for showing that string interpolation approach. Doesn't matter but I think `10.times.map { }` is more readable (i.e. duck-typing, expressing intent)